# Connectionstring of netezza with .net framework VS 2013

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, netezza

I saw the connectionstring of netezza ODBC with .NET framework and its make me confude example:

```
Driver={any odbc driver's name};OdbcKey1=someValue;OdbcKey2=someValue;
```

Please help me explain what's any odbc driver's name what's somevalue in OdbcKey1 and OdbcKey2

The detail of server information is following

```
Data Source=10.209.46.210:5480;User ID=kbanke2e;Password=1234;Initial Catalog=EDW
```

Answer (score 1):

When connecting to `Netezza` in `.net` use this instead

```
"Driver=NetezzaSQL; Server=10.209.46.210; Port=5480; Database=EDW; Persist Security Info=true; UID=kbanke2e; PWD=1234"
```